# What was the name of Monty's ship on Firefly?

Tags: firefly

In the TV show Firefly, Actor Franc Ross plays the part of Monty. He has a crew and a ship but they are unnamed in the show or credits. Does anyone know the ships name? Does anyone have info on the crew? Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

The [script](http://www.myths.com/pub/tv/firefly/script-trash.html) just refers to it as **"Monty's Ship".**

> EXT. DUST PLANET - NIGHT
>
> **MONTY'S SHIP as its engines FIRE UP**, whipping a small cloud of dust
>   around the tiny figures of Saffron and Mal. (Note: the design of this
>   ship must be such that it can take off without its engines
>   incinerating what is directly beneath it.)
>
> SAFFRON stands with her arms crossed, looking up irritably, lit by the
>   OS glare of the ship's lights. Mal is in the BG, with the crates. He
>   dabs at his bloody nose with a white kerchief. Monty's voice echoes
>   down over the SHIP'S LOUDSPEAKER, choked with hurt.

His crew are referred to as **ND (*non-descript*) Crew.**

> **MONTY:** *Where's that sorry-ass ship a' yours?*
>
> As they speak, **Monty's ND CREW** continues off-loading the crates,
>   passing in and out of frame.

---

We're informed in the official [Firefly Role-Playing Game Corebook](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/128012/Firefly-RolePlaying-Game-Corebook) that his ship is called the '***Restless Sole***'

> **Monty's Transport Ship:** Smugglers like Monty need a boat with a lot of
>   room. The ***Restless Sole*** is spacious and can hold three times the cargo
>   of a normal ship on account of its flat structure and hidden
>   compartments—some of which are built into the hull and flooring.
>   Though she's slow, the freighter can withstand an attack and still
>   stay afloat. Her size, coupled with her speed, does make her a target
>   for the Alliance. However, the *Restless Sole*'s massive cargo bay makes
>   it near impossible to inspect in any amount of reasonable time.